# How can I make the dropdown list overlay the outside card?

Tags: jquery, css, material-design-lite

I have a dropdown list inside the Google Material Design card. When clicking the button, the dropdown list would not overlay the card. I have tried to set the `z-index` to a larger value but it did not work.

Here is my [jsfiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/vr8spmnm/27/).

Comment: So you want the drop down menu out of the box?

Comment: A precondition for questions here is that all the necessary information to answer the question is added into the question itself. Since this only contains an external link, it would be regarded as off-topic. Would you transfer the relevant part of the JavaScript to the question itself, using the formatting tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not show outside the card because it's parent have `overflow:hidden` property.

So, You need to add css for that :

```
.mdl-card {
      overflow: visible !important;
}
```

```css
.status-card {
  min-height: 15% !important;
  display: block !important;
}
.mdl-card {
  overflow: visible !important;
}

.status-card > .mdl-card__supporting-text {
  margin-bottom:0px !important;
}

.status-card > .mdl-card__supporting-text > .mdl-cell--10-col {
  padding: 8% 0 8% 2%;
}

.status-card span,
color: black;
}

.status-card li:before,
content: '■';
padding-right: 0.5em;
font-size: 170%; /* or whatever */
}

.status-card ul,
max-height: 140px;
overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-lite/1.1.3/material.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.indigo-pink.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-lite/1.1.3/material.min.js"></script>

<div class="status-card mdl-card mdl-cell mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-cell--3-col">                  
  <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text mdl-grid mdl-grid--no-spacing" style="margin-left: 4%;">                        
    <button id="test1" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised" style="margin-top: 8%"></button>
    <ul class="mdl-menu mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-js-ripple-effect--ignore-events" for="test1">
      <li class="mdl-menu__item" style="color: #cd8daa;"><span>xyz</span></li>
      <li class="mdl-menu__item" style="color: #cd8daa;"><span>yue</span></li>
      <li class="mdl-menu__item" style="color: #cd8daa;"><span>24</span></li>
    </ul>                       
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col" style="display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap;">
      <h6 title="">TEST</h6>                            
    </div>                                     
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you kindly suggest how to make the dropdown list top all the other if there are more than one cards? https://jsfiddle.net/rwxh5ecd/2/

Comment: You can add using `z-index` on the first card more then the other card.. check here.. https://jsfiddle.net/vr8spmnm/36/

Answer (score 1):

Add overflow

```
.status-card {
    min-height: 15% !important;
    display: block !important;
    overflow:visible;
}
```

give this one id="status-card-1"

```
#status-card-1{
  z-index:20;
}
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vr8spmnm/37/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you kindly suggest how to make the dropdown list top all the other if there are more than one cards? https://jsfiddle.net/rwxh5ecd/2/

Answer (score 1):

The dropdown list doesn't overlay the card because ".mdl-card" has "overflow:hidden". 
You can override ".mdl-card" with value "overflow: inherit" or "overflow:visible"